# Linked list in mips assembly

Tags: list, mips

```
# 1st item - head of the list!
n1_d: .word 1
n1_n: .word n2_d  # point to (beginning of) n2

# 3rd item
n3_d: .word 3
n3_n: .word n4_d

# 2nd item
n2_d: .word 2
n2_n: .word n3_d

# 5th item
n5_d: .word 5
n5_n: .word 0 # This is the last item in the list

# 4th item
n4_d: .word 4
n4_n: .word n5_d
```

I have a linked list in mips and I want to load every element with a logical way. For example 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
How I can do it with one loop?

Comment: By traversing the list..? It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: I forgot to say that I want to do this with one loop. Yes by traversing the list

Comment: So, do you know how to traverse a singly linked list in general? If not, read a book on data structures. If you do, then you need to explain exactly what it is that you're having trouble with.